# Maintains speed when I let off the gas

Tags: acceleration, cruise-control, impala

My 02 impala is either maintaining or picks up speed after I let off the gas pedal. It's almost acting like the cruise control in on, so I pulled the fuse to the cruise. The problem stopped for a week or so, then started doing it again,and it does it randomly,  .. any ideas on why it's doing this?

Comment: Does it idle high in park or neutral?

Answer (score 4):

My Honda did this, I found it was the floor mat getting jammed against the gas pedal. Other than this it could be:

1. Worn out gas pedal cable, replace it.
2. Extremely dirty throttle body that is sticking, in this case clean the throttle body with approved throttle body spray cleaner.

Comment: Was it a Honda or [Toyota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009%E2%80%9311_Toyota_vehicle_recalls#Floor_mat_recall)?  Either way, a floor mat is a good suspect.

Comment: My 89 Honda Accord, it does not have the floor mat hook like later years do.

Comment: Aside from the cable, the OP could also have a bad throttle plate or throttle plate shaft. @Nick, this is a safety issue. Have it fixed ASAP.